# A continent formed entirely by volcanism, possible or not?

Tags: science-based, geology

Could a continent roughly the size of Europe, Africa and North-America combined be formed almost entirely due to volcanic action?

[image] Something with a similar formation to this.

From a chain of volcanoes the size of Yellowstone maybe? Sprouting over a platformy/plate thingy (can't remember how it's called right now) already in existence.

the volcanoes do **not** need to be active. Actually they need to be old enough to not be active.

Comment: Quick answer, no.

Comment: Continents are not formed by volcanic action. Basically, continents are [areas of continental crust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent) which are above sea level. (There are "submerged continents", areas of continental crust which are under the sea; see [Zealandia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zealandia).) Continental crust and oceanic crust are qualitatively different. Volcanoes do not enter the equation.

Comment: Not related to the actual question, but I don't understand the letters at your graphic. If those are supposed to be compass directions, i.e. surrounding a south polar region, then this is not how east and west work. (All directions away from the south pole are north, east and west are ↻ and ↺.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann ?

Comment: @shieldedtulip East and West are relative. There is no east pole or west pole of the earth. There is no East side or West side of the earth. There is no eastern hemisphere or western hemisphere, the way there is a northern or southern hemisphere. If you are in China, east is still in the same direction it is if you are in America. So to say 'up' and 'down' on the map are 'north', but 'right' is east and 'left' is west, is interesting.

Comment: @JustinThyme I know that east and west are relative, (I remember that much from geography classes ;)and to a point so are north and south. Every point is always relative to another given point. If you are in the northern hemisphere unless you are **on** the pole point, you can always move further north. And the same works for the south. Besides... as far as I remember, you mark your meridians taking Greenwich as 0. so you could say that technically there is a east and there is a west.

Comment: It's your world. Concepts of compass directions only apply in a world with a magnetic field that goes north to south. If your world has a multi-pole magnetic field, your compass points will be different. I was only responding to the (?) post, to explain the @Paŭlo Ebermann post. That is why I referred to it as 'interesting', not 'incorrect'. You get to use whatever convention you want on your planet. Absolutely no reason to impose our earth-centric compass conventions to your world.

Comment: @JustinThyme Got it... Thanks. I'm trying to build it as much alike Earth as I can, with a few twists. Not easy if I want to apply physics, the little I remember of it, and other earthbound rules/laws. But you are right, I can just make something up... it would certainly help me with my traveling problems... One question I no longer need to post ;)

Comment: There is a difference between being constrained by physics, and  a purely earth-centric bias. Only the earth is totally earth-like. Every planet and moon we have discovered in our solar system has distinctly non-earth-like characteristics, and will require unique solutions. For instance, the concept of  'continents' is not universally applicable to all moons and planets, and neither is plate tectonics.

Comment: ctd Same with magnetic fields and the ability to use a compass. North and South can refer to the center of rotation, while east and west can refer to a magnetic field that is on a perpendicular to the axis of rotation. Nothing in astrophysics demands that the magnetic field has to follow the axis of rotation.

Comment: @JustinThyme I keep forgetting I'm not on earth and that I can draw from other examples...

Comment: Of course you can name the directions as you want, though I'm not sure if introducing a east or west pole makes sense, or you should have other names for them. (Though if your planet rotates around a fixed axis, then naming the two poles north and south is sensible, and the circular directions around them east and west too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer no, long answer maybe you could create that much landmass but it probably wouldn't be contiguous, also the continent kind of has to be there already. Take a very large, shallow sea, thousands of square kilometers in all, add 2500 cubic kilometers of ash and debris (roughly what erupted from Yellowstone 2.1 million years ago) it's going to be a more or less circular distribution slightly distorted by prevailing winds and thickest in the centre. There would by definition have to be continental crust under the sea in the first place or it wouldn't be shallow enough for the ash and debris to raise the surface above sea level, a bit like New Zealand's underwater continent; the huge area of continental rock out to the East of the South Island.

Comment: That's what I am trying to ask about. I have an old continent, the center of it needs to have a crater or set of craters, need to be sort of rounded in shape (all the craters together). The continent does have quite a few volcanoes but not all of them are active.

Comment: @shieldedtulip The word you're looking for is [Caldera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caldera), it's a perfectly reasonable set up.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. And yes, there is an example in our solar system. It actually exists. Except that there are currently no oceans. But when there were, it would have been.

It's on [mars](http://geology.com/articles/highest-point-on-mars.shtml).

> The highest point was built by repeated eruptions of Olympus Mons, the
>   largest volcano in our solar system. Although Mars is a smaller planet
>   than Earth, the heights and depths of these features are enormous in
>   comparison.

A volcanic mountain over 13 miles high. Does that qualify?

Comment: And note the impact crater - 'Hellas Impact Crater (also known as Hellas Planitia) is an enormous impact crater in the southern hemisphere of Mars. It is about 2,300 kilometers (1,400 miles) in diameter and about 9 kilometers (5 miles) deep. It is the largest impact crater on the planet. NASA Image.'.. Big enough? Put them together, and I think you have your world.

Comment: How could I have forgotten Mars? Thank you. Any volcano on an earth-like planet, with greater gravity than Mars, would cause a similar formation, right? It would depend on the severity of the vulcanism not gravity.

Comment: But Olympus Mons is as large as it is because of no crustal drift on Mars, it seems.

Comment: Yes, the trick is to not have the plate move, so repeated eruptions over eons are possible.

Comment: Mars does not currently have plate tectonics. There is just one massive plate encompassing all of Mars. That is, all of Mars is just one continent. Same with the Moon.

Comment: For counting as a continent, the height is not that important, more the area or diameter. Olympus Mons has a diameter of 600 km (i.e. an area of < 300 000 km², which is still quite small for a continent (for comparison, the Indian subcontinent has an area of 4.4 millions km², which is 15 times that).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Provided your planet HAS plate tectonics. Mars is one solid plate.

Answer (score 3):

A single volcano would definitely not suffice to create a continent of such a size. You would require a  ring or chains of volcanoes to create a larger structure; you may look for example at japan for comparison of creating a larger archipel in such a way. Volcanic eruption in itself would however not be enough to create a whole continent, in particular not of the size you want. Without plate tectonics and large land masses pushing up the continental surface from underneath the sea level, the formation of such a large continent is impossible. You can compare the 'super-continent' Pangaea from earth's own history.

Comment: So, not one volcano but several. No problem, got enough of those on my planet. But wouldn't, over time, several volcanoes erupting at the same time create enough surface/land? Let's say they are lined up nicely, and some gather around the largest one, wouldn't that help create land? I know plate tectonics are needed, but volcanoes make landmasses faster, don't they?

Comment: @shieldedtulip: Volcanoes make *tiny* landmasses, if they make any durable landmass at all. Look at Hawaii; it's the best you can hope to get from volcanoes. If Hawaii looks like a continent to you, then fine. Not to mention that areas of widespread volcanism tend to appear at the boundary between two tectonic plates...

Comment: @AlexP sorry, not trying to be argumentative, just trying to get away from having to fiddle too much with my world. Which I guess I'll have to do. I wasn't discounting plate tectonics, just need a different landmass formation which would allow me to have a large, very large crater at the center of my continent. Or maybe a collection of craters looking something like this  https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ce/97/b1/ce97b1041aafa22bd4868fdb7c766207--crater-lake-oregon-oregon-usa.jpg Only larger.

Comment: Yellowstone *is* a large crater... The largest in the world. Formations like the one in your picture are inherently unstable; volcanic craters look like that only when they are very very young. You cannot really have a very very large *active* crater, because for a significant length of time after a [super-eruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervolcano) nothing much lives on a [very large area around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huckleberry_Ridge_Tuff)...

Comment: Venus doesn't seem to have plate tectonics (though admittedly we don't know all that much about its geology), but has continent-like areas ("terras") of high elevation: https://sos.noaa.gov/datasets/venus-topography/

Comment: @ jamesqf Mars definitely does not currently have plate tectonics. It is one large plate. So is the moon.

Comment: @Justin Thyme: Yes, I know about the Moon and Mars.  My comment was about Venus, which is a different planet :-)  But note that both the Moon and Mars have highlands and lowlands.  In the case of Mars, there's strong evidence that the lowland basins were oceans in the distant past.  And the highlands are much larger than than Olympus Mons: https://attic.gsfc.nasa.gov/mola/images/tharsis-valles-s1.jpg

Answer (score 3):

technically all continents were formed by volcanic activity in the planet's early history, of course the term volcano does not mean much wehn the entire planets surface was lava. But I assume you are talking about in modern times, in which case the answer is not without killing every living thing on the planet. The best you can manage is something the size of the [deccan traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deccan_Traps) but you are still talking about a mass extinction event.

Yellowstone is a hotspot induced composite volcano these can only occur on an existing continent otherwise you end up with something like Hawaii which you can see is not enough to produce a continent. Even with multiple eruptions the biggest you can get is something like the deccan traps or possibly Iceland or Japan. Volcanoes are rather tiny compared to the continents.

Comment: I need an old old continent. not new one. Just a very large caldera type thing, old enough (volcano/volcanic chain) to not be active, surrounded by more old volcanoes, some active some not, and a very large landmass. Would something like this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is perfectly possible. I can name an example. The Tharsis Bulge, which is the is the size of North America.
The Tharsis Bulge is one giant volcano, in fact. The world would need to have little to none tectonic activity, like Mars, but its volcanic activity could be crazy high.
These would be the type of continents to form on Bathypelagic(normal earth ocean depth) Oceanic worlds, as no tectonic activity is why Bathypelagic Oceanic worlds exist.